# registration-required(407) Error Quickblox android

Tags: android, quickblox

When I am trying to call joinRoom() or createRoom() method.I am getting two different error

```
"registration-required(407)" 
"feature-not-implemented(501) Will me done soon".
```

for reference purpose,I have posted code also.I already posted this issue on quickblox discussion board but nobody has solution.

```
QBChatService.getInstance().joinRoom(roomName,  roomReceivingListener);
String roomName="myroom";
roomReceivingListener = new RoomListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCreatedRoom(QBChatRoom qbChatRoom)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "on Created Room listener");
                chatRoom = qbChatRoom;
                //chatRoom.addMessageListener(chatMessageListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onJoinedRoom(QBChatRoom qbChatRoom)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "on Joined Room listener");
                chatRoom = qbChatRoom;
                //QBChatService.getInstance().joinRoom(chatRoom,  roomReceivingListener);
                //chatRoom.addMessageListener(chatMessageListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String msg)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "on join Room error listener");

            }
        };
```

Comment: What is your roomName?

Comment: @AjayKumar have you solved this issue?